# Regex for a particular code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on a form validation and i need a pattern for a paricular type of code.
it's like this:XXXX99999999.
 this is the regex i made myself:`[A-Za-z]{4}d{8}$`
but it doesn't work

Comment: Should be `\d` not just `d` for matching digits.

Comment: go to https://regex101.com/ to test wour regex they will tell you whats wrong

Comment: It should be [A-Za-z]{4}\d{8}$

Comment: @user3430205 update your answer with the  code don't post the code related to your question in the comments

Comment: this is the code ' <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="na" class="control-label"> Code permanent </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="na"  id="na"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}d{8}$" placeholder="XXXX99999999" required>
   </div>
  </div><br/><br/><br/>'

Comment: @user3430205 as already mentioned before – you simply forgot \ before d .

Comment: So with this pattern([A-Za-z]{4}\d{8}$ ),could you give example of true values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[A-Z]{4}\d{8}
```

check it out here: http://regexr.com/3ao9d

Answer (score 0):

```
 var regex=/^[A-Za-z]{4}\d{8}$/
```

Test this in Developer console

```
var str="XXXX99999999";
str.match(regex)
```